# How to redirect on JSF using PrimeFaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, servlet-filters

I'm trying to do a basic security system on JSF where if the user is not logged in and try to access a restricted page he will be redirected to login.xhtml. This is done in a servlet filter.

My problem is that when using resp.sendRedirect("login.xhtml"); the login page loses all resources, css, scripts, etc. So the page is displayed without any style.

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
<context-param>
<param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
<param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
<servlet>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
<load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
<session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
<filter>
<filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
<filter-class>br.com.jetcar.filter.RestrictionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>restrict</filter-name>
<url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
<servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

template.xhtml

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
      "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">
<h:head>
    <h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js"/>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="template.css" />
    <h:outputScript name="clock.js" library="js"></h:outputScript>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Bem-Vindo</ui:insert></title>
</h:head>
<body>
 <p:growl id="messages"/>  
    <div id="header">
        <ui:insert name="header">
            <div id="headerTitle">JetCar</div>
            <div id="clock"></div>
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="menu">
        <ui:insert name="menu">
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <ui:insert name="content">
        </ui:insert>
    </div>

    <div id="footer">
        <ui:insert name="footer">
            <p>Desenvolvido por</p>
            <p>Rodrigo Cavalcante de Souza</p>
            <p>Jorge Luis</p>
        </ui:insert>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

login.xhtml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<ui:composition template="resources/template/template.xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<ui:define name="title">Login</ui:define>
<ui:define name="content">


</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

The index.xhtml looks the sames as the login, since I'm still testing, what could be the problem?

error from chrome console

```
 GET http://localhost:8080/JetCar/javax.faces.resource/growl/assets/login.xhtml 404  (Not Found)
login.xhtml:3GET http://localhost:8080/JetCar/javax.faces.resource/themes/sam/login.xhtml 404 (Not Found)
login.xhtml:6GET http://localhost:8080/JetCar/javax.faces.resource/jquery/login.xhtml 404 (Not Found)
login.xhtml:6GET http://localhost:8080/JetCar/javax.faces.resource/login.xhtml 404 (Not Found)
login.xhtml:6GET http://localhost:8080/JetCar/javax.faces.resource/core/login.xhtml 404 (Not Found)
login.xhtml:4GET http://localhost:8080/JetCar/javax.faces.resource/login.xhtml 404 (Not Found)
login.xhtml:6GET http://localhost:8080/JetCar/javax.faces.resource/growl/login.xhtml 404 (Not Found)
login.xhtml:10Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
chrome-extension://ffdcfjdljhbehggjdkdioajnknjcpbjb/js/sbc_cookies_mon.js:1Uncaught   TypeError: Cannot read property 'tagName' of null
```

I'm using primefaces 2.2.1, glassfish 3.1, JSF 2.0

EDIT: I just noticed that the resources use the .xhtml extension as well, so it was interfering with the filter.

FIX:`if(req.getSession().getAttribute("func") == null && !pageRequested.contains("login.xhtml") && !pageRequested.contains("/javax.faces.resource"))
            resp.sendRedirect("login.xhtml");`

Answer (score 17):

I often use this way to redirect it directly from Java Bean:
`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(Url);`

Answer (score 3):

The proper way of redirecting pages on JSF specially in JSF 2 is returning the name of the view from the method call:

For example:

```
public String doLogin() {
    //apply the login logic.
    return "name/of/the/view?facesRedirect=true"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your filter is redirecting HTTP requests to JSF resources as well. You need to change your filter logic to add a check if the current request isn't a JSF resource request. You can do that by checking if the request URI does not start with [`ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/application/ResourceHandler.html#RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER) after the context path.

```
if (request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
else {
    response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/login.xhtml");
}
```